# Javascript validation for a html form not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

----------SOLVED------------

I'm trying to do a validation for a form so that if any of the fields are left blank, there is an alert and the form wont go through, but it is still inputting null values into the database

```js
function validateAdd() {
  var a = document.add_product.product_id.value;
  var b = document.add_product.brand.value;
  var c = document.add_product.model.value;
  var h = document.add_product.description.value;
  var d = document.add_product.cam_mpx.value;
  var e = document.add_product.storage.value;
  var f = document.add_product.more_storage.value;
  var g = document.add_product.price.value;
  if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "" || d == "" || e == "" || f = "" || g == "" || h == "" ||
    a == null || b == null || c == null || d == null || e == null || f = null || g == null || h == null) {
    alert("All fields must be filled in");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="add_product" action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateAdd()">
  <label>Product ID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="product_id"><br>
  <label>Brand:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="brand"><br>
  <label>Model:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="model"><br>
  <label>Description:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="description"><br>
  <label>Camera Megapixel:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="cam_mpx"><br>
  <label>Storage:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="storage"><br>
  <label>Expandable Storage?:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="more_storage"><br>
  <label>Price:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="price"><br>
  <button class="button" type="submit" name="save" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this to the system?')">Add</button><br>
  <p></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the Javascript to see what the values are? Every major browser has these debugging tools built in.

Comment: AN input's value is not going to equal null.

Comment: What is the console output? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: What exactly does "it wont work" mean?  It won't work _how_?  You're getting an error? If so, what's the error?  It's saying something isn't valid when you think it should be?  It's saying that everything is valid when you think it should tell you something is invalid?  You need to be more specific here.

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Comment: what does  
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" do and how would I go about fixing this? Sorry still pretty new.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can avoid that hyper-long condition (which causes problems), and do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6ammw8ac/

Comment: Thank you very much sinisake! That works cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, on these two lines, you do `f = ""` and `f = null` instead of `f == ""` and `f == null`:

```
if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "" || d == "" || e == "" || f = "" || g == "" || h == ""
        || a == null || b == null || c == null || d == null || e == null || f = null || g == null || h == null) {
```

You would have noticed to look there from `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` being errored to the console.

I would suggest that you shorten that down to

```
if (!(a && b && c && d && e && f && g && h)) {
```

because it's way easier to debug.

Comment: still didnt work and still attempted to input values into the database